# Does an enlightened person have access to whatever information he wants?

Tags: nirvana, enlightenment, arahant

I am following a guy online who claims to be enlightened. Everything about him is fine and he seems genuine and all but for one reason that he says he has no recollection of his past lives.

Is this possible? Also, on similar lines, if one gets enlightened will he have access to whatever information he wants. Not an all-knowing one, but just that which he needs or wills.

Comment: So long as there's a nearby internet connection, then this might be true for everyone. However, there is a different kind of knowing, one that is not governed by intellect, words or language. It is this **knowing** or **discernment** that one begins to tune into. One becomes familiar with what that sense of knowing is like for them. It is a knowing that is absent of thought, but it can use thought as an extension to express itself. That is what sharing the dhamma is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Buddha stated that it is possible to be all-knowing, but not all at once.

That means it is possible for the Buddha to know and understand all things if he tried to learn it, but not simultaneously. This means he has the capacity to know all things, but it doesn't mean that he indeed knew all things.

> Then the king said to the Buddha, “I have heard, sir, that the ascetic
> Gotama says this: ‘There is no ascetic or brahmin who will claim to be
> all-knowing and all-seeing, to know and see everything without
> exception: that is not possible.’ Do those who say this repeat what
> the Buddha has said, and not misrepresent him with an untruth? Is
> their explanation in line with the teaching? Are there any legitimate
> grounds for rebuke and criticism?”
>
> “Great king, those who say this do not repeat what I have said. They
> misrepresent me with what is false and untrue.” ....
>
> Then the king said to the Buddha, “Sir, might the Buddha have spoken
> in reference to one thing, but that person believed it was something
> else? How then do you recall making this statement?”
>
> “Great king, I recall making this statement: ‘There is no ascetic or
> brahmin who knows all and sees all **simultaneously**: that is not
> possible.’”
>
> “What the Buddha says appears reasonable.
> [MN 90](https://suttacentral.net/mn90/en/sujato)

But what kind of knowledge does the Buddha definitely possess? According to [MN 71](https://suttacentral.net/mn71/en/sujato) (quoted below), he definitely possessed the three knowledges, and at the same time he denied complete omniscience.

As for knowledge apart from the three knowledges, the Buddha possessed the capacity to know and understand them, but he does not know them all at once.

> “Sir, I have heard this: ‘The ascetic Gotama claims to be all-knowing
> and all-seeing, to know and see everything without exception, thus:
> “Knowledge and vision are constantly and continually present to me,
> while walking, standing, sleeping, and waking.”’ I trust that those
> who say this repeat what the Buddha has said, and do not misrepresent
> him with an untruth? Is their explanation in line with the teaching?
> Are there any legitimate grounds for rebuke and criticism?”
>
> “Vaccha, those who say this do not repeat what I have said. They
> misrepresent me with what is false and untrue.”
>
> “So how should we answer so as to repeat what the Buddha has said, and
> not misrepresent him with an untruth? How should we explain in line
> with his teaching, with no legitimate grounds for rebuke and
> criticism?”
>
> “‘The ascetic Gotama has the three knowledges.’ Answering like this
> you would repeat what I have said, and not misrepresent me with an
> untruth. You would explain in line with my teaching, and there would
> be no legitimate grounds for rebuke and criticism.
> [MN 71](https://suttacentral.net/mn71/en/sujato)

However, much later tradition exaggerated the claims of the Buddha's omniscience, for e.g. [Mil 6.2.8](https://suttacentral.net/mil6.2.8/en/tw_rhysdavids) and [Mil 3.6.2](https://suttacentral.net/mil3.6.2/en/tw_rhysdavids). The Milindapanha was authored 400 to 700 years after the Buddha's passing away.

In [Mil 6.2.8](https://suttacentral.net/mil6.2.8/en/tw_rhysdavids), Ven. Nagesena was asked why did the Buddha introduce the monastic rules little by little rather than altogether at once, since he was omniscient. He answered that although the Buddha knew all the monastic rules from the beginning, he did not want to scare people with too many rules, so he introduced new rules only when they were needed.

In [Mil 3.6.2](https://suttacentral.net/mil3.6.2/en/tw_rhysdavids), Ven. Nagesena was asked the same question, but here he answered that a physician dispenses medicine only after the disease shows symptoms, even if he knew how to treat all diseases.

[Mil 6.2.8](https://suttacentral.net/mil6.2.8/en/tw_rhysdavids) and [Mil 3.6.2](https://suttacentral.net/mil3.6.2/en/tw_rhysdavids) make the same kind of excuses that was ridiculed in [MN 76](https://suttacentral.net/mn76/en/sujato) (quoted below). So, I feel that it is not good to unnecessarily exaggerate claims about the Buddha, as it will put off intelligent people from learning the Buddha's teachings.

> “Sandaka, take a certain teacher who claims to be all-knowing and
> all-seeing, to know and see everything without exception, thus:
> ‘Knowledge and vision are constantly and continually present to me,
> while walking, standing, sleeping, and waking.’ He enters an empty
> house; he gets no alms-food; a dog bites him; he encounters a wild
> elephant, a wild horse, and a wild cow; he asks the name and clan of a
> woman or man; he asks the name and path to a village or town. When
> asked, ‘Why is this?’ he answers: ‘I had to enter an empty house,
> that’s why I entered it. I had to get no alms-food, that’s why I got
> none. I had to get bitten by a dog, that’s why I was bitten. I had to
> encounter a wild elephant, a wild horse, and a wild cow, that’s why I
> encountered them. I had to ask the name and clan of a woman or man,
> that’s why I asked. I had to ask the name and path to a village or
> town, that’s why I asked.’
>
> A sensible person reflects on this matter in this way: ‘This teacher
> makes such a claim, but he answers in such a way. This spiritual life
> is unreliable.’ Realizing this, they leave disappointed.
> [MN 76](https://suttacentral.net/mn76/en/sujato)

Answer (score 1):

in buddhism, the fully enlightened are called 'Arahants'

there are Arahants, such as Sariputta, who had no psychic powers; therefore were unable to know certain worldly phenomena

then there are Maras who have psychic powers

again, considering reading: [SN 22.70](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.70/en/bodhi?reference=none&highlight=false) about how the fully enlightened are such due to wisdom rather than due to omniscience

Answer (score 0):

Depends. If it's a fully enlightened Buddha then yes - such a being can learn and understand whatever he directs his mind to.

Comment: Welcome to Buddhism Stack Exchange. The system flagged this as a low quality answer. This answer is too short and doesn't contain enough details. Also, if possible, it is preferred to cite sources to support the answer. Did you intend it to be a [comment](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) under the question? If not, please see [this guide](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to write a good answer.

Answer (score -1):

What does good householder likes to know in regard of good in this world, the next and the path beyond?

(As for the "guy". There are no householding Arahats, Buddhas or Paccekabuddhas, not even Once or No-returner in this time. Simply this, seeing one still in trading, will cut off 98% of awakened around)

Comment: this answer appears to be unsubstantiated (false) speech. however, if the poster claims to have psychic powers to justify what they wrote, this appears to be a Vinaya transgression

Answer (score -2):

there appears no such thing as recollection of "past lives" in the Buddha's teaching

there is only one sutta explaining the meaning of recollection of past "nivasa" ("abodes"; "dwellings") and it does not appear to be about "past lives"

you can read it, here: [SN 22.79](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.79/en/bodhi?reference=none&highlight=false)